# Microsoft Graph API /beta/me/findRooms not working for application?

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use the `/beta/me/findRooms` endpoint from the Microsoft Graph API using app permissions. I have created an application with (hopefully enough) permissions to do so. Running from a `node.js` application I can get the access_token needed to do such a request. However, when attempting to access `/findRooms` I keep hitting a brick wall:

```
{ error:
   { code: 'ErrorNonExistentMailbox',
     message: 'No mailbox was found that includes the specified identity: 
8370e476-a531-4529-8186-cd1d7cfe6292**@**a73fa5a8-6a60-4a98-a185-8577dbe25873.',
 innerError:
  { 'request-id': '9bce60dd-6bfe-4d38-9d8f-28308e8eb1bb',
    date: '2018-07-07T18:33:28' } } }
```

The identity seems to describe `[appId] @ [tenantId]`.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Since you're new here, I recommend reading ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some tips. Your question is lacking sufficient detail to help the community help you. Please make sure you include the code you're using to call the API, not just the error you're getting in response.

Comment: I am having the same problem too. My suspicion is that when we use the App permission access token, you can't use /me endpoint as there are no user details in the access token. You can use /users/{id}/findRooms but you won't know the user id that is signed in during the admin consent process (unless you hardcoded it). I'm wondering if there's a way to get the signed in user's information after the authentication process. Appreciate anyone who could help this.

Comment: Another way I am trying to do is to list all users via /beta/users endpoint and filter only meeting room "users". But there's no significant indication that the user is a room instead of a normal user, and the only property that could differentiate from my side is the `officeLocation`, though that is still unreliable.